# Excel VBA - Data Validation - Indirect List Error '1004'

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to indirectly reference a list in VBA but keep hitting Run Time Error 1004.

I need to add data validation to the range defined below, which will look at the value of the cell in the previous column to determine what list to show.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Select
 With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT(RC[-1])"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

NB I have also tried;

```
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=INDIRECT($P2)"
```

Comment: what is the value in P2? it must be a range address

Comment: It will be 1 of three options,
either "Blank", Value1 or Value 2. IF P2 = Value1 then return List1 in Q2 OR IF P2 = Value2 then return List2 in Q2.

Comment: @Rosetta, range address was enough for me to work out where I went wrong. Thanks for the prompt. I have just populated the range with a Temporary "BlankList" which I will delete after the validation has happened. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome